# ArcGIS temporal relationship between two feature layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, time

how can I built a temporal relation between two feature layers.

My first layer has a observation time period and my second feature has the actual observation. I would like to build the relation directly in ArcGIS using the python console.

What I need is a function which:

1. iterates through the second feature and
2. checks if the time condition with the first feature attributes are fulfilled and
3. returns the corresponding id.

My features have the following structure:

***First feature layer***

```
ID    DATE        START    END
1     2015-03-29  13:20    14:50
2     2015-04-05  08:35    12:05
```

***Second feature layer***

```
ID    DATE        TIME    IDfirstLayer 
1     2015-03-29  13:23   0
2     2015-03-29  13:28   0
3     2015-03-29  13:34   0
4     2015-03-29  13:49   0
5     2015-04-05  08:39   0
6     2015-04-05  10:04   0
7     2015-04-05  11:35   0
```

I guess, beside the loop function, I need to build a timestamp for each date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use two embedded [cursors]:

[1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000008000000) first [update]

[2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/) and then [search]

[3](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/), here is a general sample.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(firstLayer, fields) as cursorfirstLayer:
    for rowfirstLayer in cursorfirstLayer:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(secondLayer, fields2) as cursorsecondLayer:
            for rowsecondLayer in cursorsecondLayer:
                # continue with if conditional logic and apply value updates
```

You can then use the date module to pull current date for assigning time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example how to use the code from **[@artwork21](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/158864/53268)**

```py
# selected features and columns
firstLayer = "opservation_polinien"
fields = ["opservationID", "DATE", "TIME"]
secondLayer = "opservation_point"
fields2 = ["opservationID", "DATE", "START", "END"]

# loop through features
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(firstLayer, fields) as cursorfirstLayer:
    for rowfirstLayer in cursorfirstLayer:
        opservationTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(rowfirstLayer[1]+' '+rowfirstLayer[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        locId = 0
        rowfirstLayer[0] = locId # reset all to 0
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(secondLayer, fields2) as cursorsecondLayer:
            for rowsecondLayer in cursorsecondLayer:
                opservationStart = datetime.datetime.strptime(rowsecondLayer[1]+' '+rowsecondLayer[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                opservationEnd = datetime.datetime.strptime(rowsecondLayer[1]+' '+rowsecondLayer[3], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                # continue with if conditional logic and apply value updates
                if opservationTime > opservationStart and opservationTime < opservationEnd and worker == opservationWorker:
                    locId = rowsecondLayer[0]
                    rowfirstLayer[0] = locId # set ID
        cursorfirstLayer.updateRow(rowfirstLayer) # save update
```